# Is there any way i can get handle on value from views Column header?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Is there any way i can get handle on value  from views Column header??

I have one view and i have to display only selected column values inside a table with respect to the selected column header.

```
var colNames = new Array(); var Title=sessionScope.dbTitle; 
var vwName =     sessionScope.vwTitle;     
print ("view name"+ vwName);
if ((vwName != null) & (vwName != "Select")) { //var vwName="vwDbConfig";
print (vwName); 
var dbpath=@DbLookup("","vwDbConfig",Title,3);
var serName=@DbLookup("","vwDbConfig",Title,2);
var ArchDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(serName,dbpath);
//var ArchDb:NotesDatabase= database;
var Archvw:NotesView = ArchDb.getView(vwName);
var names:java.util.Vector = Archvw.getColumnNames();
```

Comment: please, add more details to your question

Comment: var colNames = new Array(); 
var Title=sessionScope.dbTitle;
var vwName = sessionScope.vwTitle;
print ("view name"+ vwName);
if ((vwName != null) & (vwName != "Select")) 
{
//var vwName="vwDbConfig";
print (vwName);
var dbpath=@DbLookup("","vwDbConfig",Title,3);
var serName=@DbLookup("","vwDbConfig",Title,2);
var ArchDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(serName,dbpath);

//var ArchDb:NotesDatabase= database;
var Archvw:NotesView = ArchDb.getView(vwName);
var names:java.util.Vector = Archvw.getColumnNames();

Comment: You should edit the question to include the source code. The comment makes it incredibly difficult to read it.

Comment: Still don't get it. But let me guess: you want to select from list of column titles and show view/table with values of selected columns only?

Comment: @Frantisek Kossuth Yes..thats what my question is.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: two repeats. Outermost repeat will iterate through view entries of binded view data source, variable "row". Inner repeat will iterate through collection of numbers - each represents index of selected column, variable "column". Repeat will render inside `<td>` tag computed text with binding `row.getColumnValues().get(column)`. Adopt it to proper data type if necessary. Don't forget to add proper tags for header and rows.